# uwp app reposition to bottom left of screen

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, window, windows-community-toolkit

I want to reposition a uwp app everytime it opens, to bottom left just above the taskbar, to mimic start menu like behavior.

> I have tried using **AppWindow** class to create secondary views and resize and reposition them with the build in methods, but the problem is there is no appwindow instance for the main window.

```
AppWindow = await AppWindow.TryCreateAsync();
AppWindow.RequestMoveRelativeToDisplayRegion(displayRegion, new Point(xpos, ypos));
AppWindow.RequestSize(new Size(wWidth, wHeight));
```

> In case of **ApplicationView** for the main window only resizing method is available.

```
var view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
view.TryResizeView(new Size(wWidth, wHeight));
```

So technically I need to do calculations based on display region (monitor) and then place the app on bottom left and also resize it to a specific size depending on monitor effective pixels, resizing isnt the problem as their is a method for it, but moving and repositioning the app window to a specific place on the screen is a problem as there is no method for it.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set window position programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57795210/set-window-position-programmatically)

Comment: maybe , but its a couple years old question, so maybe there is a work around now? are u sure there isnt?

Comment: No, I'm not sure. But if you need to position your window and you want modern look, you should consider WinUI 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> moving and repositioning the app window to a specific place on the screen is a problem as there is no method for it.

Yes, UWP doesn't have the API that could change its position in the system as mentioned here:[UWP Window Placement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048576/uwp-window-placement) and [How to set UWP app position (x & y coordinates)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/434639/how-to-set-uwp-app-position-x-amp-y-coordinates-so.html) . Although this is an old question, the answer doesn't change. The position of the UWP window can't be controlled from the app level.